# How do I programmatically execute a link button within a FormView with a commandName in ASP.Net?

Tags: c#, asp.net, formview, linkbutton

I have a the following `linkbutton` within an `InsertItemTemplate` in a `FormView` control:

```
<InsertItemTemplate>
    <asp:Table runat="server" id="tabInst">
        <asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Instrument ID:</asp:TableCell>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox id="tbID" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("InstID")%>' MaxLength="20"/>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbID" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter an Instrument ID">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CustomValidator ID="compValID" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbID" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" OnServerValidate="compValID_ServerValidate" ErrorMessage="That InstrumentID already exists">*</asp:CustomValidator>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Instrument Name:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox id="tbName" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name")%>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValName" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbName" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter an Instrument Name">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Exchange Symbol:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbExchSym" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("ExchSymbol") %> MaxLength="20"></asp:TextBox>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Instrument Type:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddInstType" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsInstType" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" SelectedValue=<%# Bind("InstType") %>></asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Currency:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddCurr" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsCurr" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" OnInit="ddCurr_Init" SelectedValue=<%# Bind("CurrCode") %>></asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Exchange:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:DropDownList ID="ddExch" runat="server" DataSourceID="edsExch" DataTextField="Name" DataValueField="Code" OnInit="ddExch_Init" SelectedValue=<%# Bind("ExchCode") %>></asp:DropDownList>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Price Divisor:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox id="tbPriceDiv" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("PriceDiv")%>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValPriceDiv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPriceDiv" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a Price Divisor">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="compValPriceDiv" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbPriceDiv" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Price Divisor must be greater than 0" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Integer">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Tick Size:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox id="tbTickSize" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("TickSize")%>' />
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValTickSize" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbTickSize" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a Tick Size">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="compValTickSize" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbTickSize" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Tick Size must be greater than 0" Operator="GreaterThan" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Double">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow><asp:TableRow>
            <asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Settle Day Type:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:RadioButtonList ID="rblSettType" runat="server" RepeatDirection="Horizontal" SelectedValue=<%# Bind("InstType") %>>
                    <asp:ListItem Selected="True" Text="Business" Value="B" />
                    <asp:ListItem Text="Calendar" Value="C" />
                </asp:RadioButtonList>
            </asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyLabel">Settle Days:</asp:TableCell><asp:TableCell CssClass="PropertyValue">
                <asp:TextBox ID="tbSettDays" runat="server" Text=<%# Eval("SettleDays") %>></asp:TextBox>
                <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="reqValSettDays" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbSettDays" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Please enter a Settle Days">*</asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
                <asp:CompareValidator ID="compValSettDays" runat="server" ControlToValidate="tbSettDays" CssClass="Validator" Display="Dynamic" ErrorMessage="Settle Days must be greater than or equal to 0" Operator="GreaterThanEqual" ValueToCompare="0" Type="Double">*</asp:CompareValidator>
            </asp:TableCell></asp:TableRow></asp:Table><asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsCurr" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=CQPosManEntities" DefaultContainerName="CQPosManEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Currencies">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsExch" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=CQPosManEntities" DefaultContainerName="CQPosManEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="Exchanges">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <asp:EntityDataSource ID="edsInstType" runat="server" ConnectionString="name=CQPosManEntities" DefaultContainerName="CQPosManEntities" EnableFlattening="False" EntitySetName="InstTypes">
    </asp:EntityDataSource>
    <br />
    <asp:LinkButton ID="InsertButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" CommandName="Insert" Text="Insert" Visible="false" OnClick="InsertButton_Click"/>
    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="InsertCancelButton" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" CommandName="Cancel" Text="Cancel" Visible="false" />
    <asp:ValidationSummary ID="valSum1" runat="server" CssClass="Validator" HeaderText="Please correct the following errors:"  />
</InsertItemTemplate>
```

The code that calls the OnClick event is:

```
    public bool Insert()
    {
        LinkButton lbInsert = (LinkButton) fvInst.FindControl("InsertButton");
        InsertButton_Click(lbInsert, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
```

I have confirmed that I have the correct button and that the InsertButton_Click function is entered.  However, no validation is performed nor is the ItemInserting event fired which happens when the button is clicked physically.

Thanks.

Comment: Show us your code please

Comment: I tried responding with an answer but the system will not let me for 8 hours (I am new).  I will show my code behind here, but I also added a OnClick event called InsertButton_Click in the markup:  public void Insert()
{
 LinkButton lbInsert =  (LinkButton)vInst.FindControl("InsertButton");
 InsertButton_Click(lbInsert, EventArgs.Empty); }
I have confirmed that I have the correct button and the InsertButton_Click event is entered, but the Insert Command is not executed nor is the ItemInserting event, which both execute when I click the button physically.

Comment: Don't add code as a comment. It's completely unreadable. Edit your original question and add it there.

Answer (score 0):

you can move the code into a separate method and have that method called programatically.  the onclick method for linkbutton can call that method as well.